# Script function replace is not changing the cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, replace

I created this function to change specific cell value, from "5.000,00 C" to "5.000,00":

But when I run the function the cell does not change.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var FILE = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/");
  var CONTENT = FILE.getSheetByName("r2--tests");
  var A1 = CONTENT.getRange("G3").getValue()
  var A1split = A1.split(" ");
  A1.replace(A1, `${A1split[0]}`);
};
```

Comment: Assuming `A1.replace` is `String.prototype.replace` then that won't update `A1`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to update the cell:

```
CONTENT.getRange("G3").setValue(A1.replace(A1, `${A1split[0]}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the result of your replace to `A1`, and then write it back to the Spreadsheet:

```
function myFunction() {
  var FILE = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/");
  var CONTENT = FILE.getSheetByName("r2--tests");
  var A1 = CONTENT.getRange("G3").getValue()
  var A1split = A1.split(" ");
  A1 = A1.replace(A1, `${A1split[0]}`);
  CONTENT.getRange("G3").setValue(A1);
};
```